# "Start a task process" do not create tasks for all the users given in the recipient feild (SharePoint workflow 2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, tasks

I have a problem that I want to discuss here and hopefully I will get some answers.

I have recently created a workflow for a custom list (SharePoint online) in SharePoint Dsigner 2013. In workflow, main action is to create a task (also send email) for all given users at a time and for that I used "Start a Task Process" action, but the issue is that workflow is not working for large number of users (have more than 300 users). I also want to see all the names of the users for which task has been created by workflow under task inside workflow information page.I have tried to work this out in many ways (listed below) but non of it worked.

First Method: I created a user Group in SharePoint and added 200 users in that group. Then in Workflow I added that group in "Start a task process" recipient field but workflow created just one task against SharePoint group name instead of creating task for each user (I have also selected the option "create task for every user in a group" in "Start a Task Process" properties). This method worked well when I added only 6 users in a group but I need to add large number of users.

Second method: Instead of creating a group I added users directly in recipient field in "Start a task Process" action and found that I can only add 40 users at max. So I added 2 more same actions to cover my all users. This time workflow made task for  very user but it stopped in the middle of 2nd "Start a task Process" action. So it made nearly 48 tasks and stopped. I don't know if there is a maximum limit of assigning task at a time but I really want to assign task to all users in a group.

Kindly let me know if any of you have a solution for this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am currently having similar issues. I did find someone on another post with some helpful advice that may help readers of this post. Apparently you should use the user's ID in a task or email because it possible that the task or email will be sent to some users and not others. It is worth a try. It seems to have help the issue I am currently experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a task for every user just put them all into a group and where you assign your task to users simply point to this group and return field as Display Names, Semicolon Delimited. Please not that AD groups do not fire off an email, hope this helps. SharePoint can be a bit of a pain.